# Separate the multiple Html links into one link by ID in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have searched in the forum but I didn't find any solution related to my problem. I have a table which has ID and links. One Id will have multiple http links. I wanted them to Separate by ID. I am using Sql Server 2014. Please see below for the sample data.

```
| ID  | Links                          |
|:----|:-----------------------------------
|12   |https://yahoo.com  https://edu.org
|13   |https://hotmail.com
|14   |https://cnn.com  https://www.wikipedia.org/

My Expected output 

| ID  | Links                          |
|:----|:-----------------------------------
|12   |https://yahoo.com
|12   |https://edu.org
|13   |https://hotmail.com
|14   |https://cnn.com
|14   |https://www.wikipedia.org/
```

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` is supported since 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SQL Server Version >= 2016

Use `STRING_SPLIT` with `CROSS APPLY` then remove the empty strings in the `WHERE` clause.

```
 SELECT a.ID, 
           value AS Links
    FROM sample a
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(a.Links, ' ') b
    WHERE b.value <> ''
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/5oN7K-li).

### SQL Server Version < 2016

Convert your rows to an `XML` string then use SQL Server's `XML` functionality.

```
SELECT ID, Split.b.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Links
FROM
(
  SELECT ID, CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(Links, ' ', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
  FROM sample
) a
CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') Split(b)
WHERE Split.b.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') <> ''
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/R_q2rBWS).

**Result:**

| ID | Links |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | https://yahoo.com |
| 12 | https://edu.org |
| 13 | https://hotmail.com |
| 14 | https://cnn.com |
| 14 | https://www.wikipedia.org/ |

**Note:** As noted in the comments below, these are poorly performing queries. If you're expecting to run this over a long period of time and/or over a large data set you should consider moving the split values into a designated table. Also, consider adjusting the process (if you have one) that is currently inserting the `URL`'s into the table like this for a better long term approach.

Comment: Thanks Griv. I have just realized the my db server version is 2014. My bad. it there a way we can achieve this without String_Split. -- Thanks

Comment: @Naveen updated using XML functionality to achieve the same result.

Comment: note -- both of these perform poorly -- if you expect to run multiple times you should change to process to save the split values in a table.

Comment: @Hogan agreed. Good point. I will add this to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how many spaces you may have between the URLs, so this has been wrapped to avoid showing blank URLs in the results.

```
select *
  from (
   select id, value as url
     from my_data
    cross apply string_split(links, ' ')
  )z
where url <> ''
```

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Dad_aiEW).

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately I can't use String_Split function as my DB sits on 2014 Server. Please guide, if you have any alternate solution. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, yeah this was supporting the original tag of 2017.